# Power BI - RLS: adding label to a visual and aggregate values

Tags: security, powerbi

I need to set some RLSs on some tables and columns, and for a specific Matrix I want to show all the all the other values, that are not shown to that specific user, summed up together as "Others". I give you an example.

I have a matrix which on the rows and columns has different product categories and the values are the impact in $ that each category has on the others (it is the sum of multiples rows under IMPACT column in the source table). Particularly, the rows are the impacted products while the columns the impacting ones.
The Matrix looks like this:

[image]

I want to create an additional label , OTHERS, which has to be displayed both as a column and row, which sums up all the values of the non-shown values. For instance, for the RED RLS categories I want to get a matrix like this:

[image]

FYI, I want to keep the totals of the rows and columns.

Does anybody have any ideas?

I tried to create some measures and calculated tables but I was not able to get the final view I want.

Comment: This is a variant on "non visual totals".  Read: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/implement-non-visual-totals-with-power-bi-security-roles/  for one approach.